# Self-Contained Systems vs Monolithic

Tags: architecture, language-concepts

I just need to know is there is a difference between Self-Contained Systems (SCS) and the Monolithic ones, And SCS is different from microservice or it's the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a definition of self-contained systems ([source](http://scs-architecture.org/index.html)):

> The Self-contained System (SCS) approach is an architecture that
>   focuses on a separation of the functionality into many independent
>   systems, making the complete logical system a collaboration of many
>   smaller software systems. This avoids the problem of large monoliths
>   that grow constantly and eventually become unmaintainable.

So yes, self-contained systems are very different from monolithic systems.

Regarding the relationship of self-contained systems and microservices, they share the idea of breaking down the system into smaller independent subsystems. However, important differences are ([source](http://scs-architecture.org/vs-ms.html)) that

- self-contained systems do not communicate with each other,
- self-contained systems each have their own UI, whereas microservices do not necessarily have a UI or share a common one.

[This article](https://www.innoq.com/en/articles/2016/11/self-contained-systems-different-microservices/) gives another important characteristic:

> A system that just provides an API is not an SCS by definition. It
>   might still be considered a useful architecture, of course - but it
>   would not be called SCS.